# How to run the local Notepad.exe using Spring web application

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I need to run a local **notepad.exe** from Spring application. Can you please suggest me.

Comment: Do you mean that your code is running on a web server, but you want to be able to launch an executable on my machine (running a browser)? Eek, no. You can supply a text file and let me (the user) choose what application to open that in, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Spring desktop app? or spring web? Sounds a little bit weird..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec` method call from the [Runtime class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).
Like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\path\\to\\the\\executable\\notepad.exe"));
```

via [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)):

> Executes the specified string command in a separate process.
>   This is a convenience method. An invocation of the form exec(command) behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation `exec(command, null, null)`.

But IMHO it makes sense only if you use `Spring` in the desktop app. On the server side `exec` is usually used to call non-GUI executables with command line options

Answer (score 0):

Any HTTP request that you make that gets `text/plain` as a response, and that the users selects "Open" on instead of "Save" or "Save as..." will trigger the Notepad application to run, and display the response in that application.

So if you have for instance a link to...

`<a href="http://your.server/your/application?foo=bar">Click me for a text file</a>`

...and this web application responds with `text/plain`, the user should be prompted to Open or Save the response. If they select Open, then the Notepad application should open.

Comment: what if Notepad is not selected as a default app for opening text files? that's actually quite interesting problem - to open a resource in particular app when that resource is being requested

Comment: You have no control over that at all. You must remember that a web application — HTML, CSS and Javascript — are heavily sand-boxed. You, as a web developer, are **not** supposed to have that kind of control over the user's computer. It is only by **convention** that `text/plain` are directed to whatever application is currently registered to deal with 'text/plain' requests. By default that is Notepad.exe, but the user may very well change it. And there is nothing you, as the web developer, can do to enforce it. This is by design, and entirely intentional.